# Connectedness of the $S^2$ sphere

Tags: general-topology

I found a theorem that the $S^2$ is connected however I cannot find a proof via Google. Is there any hint how to proof that the $S^2$ sphere is connected?

Comment: Dear uupsklick, There are lot's of ways to prove this. You should probably provide a little more information about your background in topology (e.g. what texts you have studied from) so that people know at what level to aim their hints.  Regards,

Comment: I just started viewing topological spaces. The definition I'm trying to understand is that there are no non-intersecting, non-empty open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $M = A \cup B$.

Comment: One way, which I think will make sense if you know what "connected" means, would be to exhibit a continuous map from a connected space onto $S^2$. Can you think of such a map?

Comment: $R^2$ is connected and I can create a map such as the arcustangens to $S^2$. Am I on the correct way?

Comment: With $\arctan$? Below, Bruno gives a map that would work. Of course, you have to prove that $\mathbf R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ is path connected, but that's a good exercise too. Do you know this theorem yet, by the way? That the continuous image of a connected space is connected, I mean. Proving connectedness without using these auxiliary lemmas is usually painful: a book will usually prove directly that intervals in $\mathbf R$ are connected, and then try to make use of various [theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems) to show it for other spaces.

Comment: What are you trying to do with $\arctan$? Are you trying to show that the open unit disk in $\mathbf{R}^2$ is connected?

Comment: Also: do you know what arc-connectedness is and that it implies connectedness? otherwise, all of the answers so far won't help much... This is precisely why it is good to explain your background!

Answer (score 10):

Probably the easiest way is to notice that $S^2$ path-connected, which implies connectedness. You can join any two points on $S^2$ with a segment of a great circle.

Or you can notice that $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ is path connected, and that there exists a continuous surjective map $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\} \to S^2$.